# unmarshalItem DynamoDB & PHP not working

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, unmarshalling

I wanted to unmarshal the dynamodb scan query response and here is my code

```
$client = $this->getClient();
        $result = $client->scan([
            'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
                ':v1' => [
                    'S' => "200",
                ],
            ],
            'FilterExpression' => 'id = :v1',
            'ProjectionExpression' => "entryStamp",
            'TableName' => $this->table,
        ]);
        return $this->unmarshalItem($result['Items']);
```

It returns error "Unexpected type: entryStamp."

Comment: Looks ok. Are those double quotes around entryStamp causing the issue?

Comment: Everything was ok and I solved this by this code 

$data = [];
foreach($result['Items'] as $item){
$data[] = $this->unmarshalItem($item);
}
return $data;

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for this myself and it doesn't seem possible at the moment.

I didn't find anything specifically about PHP but [this thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/696) describe the exact same problem with GO.

So the best way to go about it is to do what Saurabh advised in his comment:

```
$result = $this->client->query($params); 

$data = [];
foreach( $result['Items'] as $item)
{
    $data[] = $marshaler->unmarshalItem($item);
}

return $data;
```